# Passing a javascript variable to a php variable on the same page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am aware that my question has been asked many times here. I have already checked dozens of answers in the last few days but I still can't make it work.

I have a select list with options as you see below. Every time a new option is selected, I want to pass the value from my JavaScript variable to a PHP variable on the same page using AJAX without loading the page and echo my php variable after "you selected :"
[image]

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>demo</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:600px;">
   <form method="post" action="">
   <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control action">
    <option value="UK">UK</option>
      <option value="USA">USA</option>
      <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
   </select>
   <br />
   <p> you selected : 
    <?php   
    if( isset($_POST['myValue']) ){
      echo $_POST['myValue'];
     exit; }
    ?> 
   </p>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.action').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() != '')
  {
   var selectedOption = $(this).val();
     $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      data: {myValue: selectedOption},
      success: function(data){
       console.log('country : ' + data);
      }
     });

  }
 });
});
</script>
```

when I check my console i see the result `console.log('country : ' + data);` which means the data is passed to my variable. But the `echo $_POST['myValue'];` doesn't show any result on my page.

Any ideas please why the echo is not shown on my page ? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your variable 'data' in JS side contain the output of `echo $_POST['myValue'];`

Comment: PHP code is executed only once when the page load and by the server, You can't update the page content using PHP without reloading your page.

Comment: Why PHP with ajax? Why did you even call here ajax? you can do it with vanilla javascript

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); ` at the top of the php script, what does it return?

Comment: This is fundamentally not how PHP and AJAX work together. You can't mix AJAX and server-side rendered HTML this way, the PHP code is evaluated once on the server when rendering the initial response.

If you want the `<?php  ... ?>` parts of the page redrawn, you either need to perform a full-page reload without AJAX, *or* update the DOM programatically in your AJAX's complete callback.

Comment: but i am using Ajax in my case and i believe it's the correct as on sucess i can see the value is passed in console